# Android Gradle | how to build debug apk for only active ABI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm refactoring my current build.gradle to support both amazon and googleplay apks.
For that I've created 2 productFlavors (amazon and googleplay), so I can set some different dependancies and manifest.xml for each flavor.
During this refactor I came to an understanding that my current gradle didn't work well.

My goal is to get 4 build variants: debug/release-amazon/googlplay.apk.
When I build a debug I want only the current active ABI to be built, but if it's a release build , build all ABIs APKs.

[image]

I succeeded to get those variants. But build only current active ABI on debug only, doesn't work for me, because I couldn't get the value of active ABI from gradle.

I couldn't find this information on "Active ABI" on the internet, so this is why I'm asking here.